# How to retrieve nested list from object using Stream API?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

Do you have any idea how to retrieve all `SimpleProperty` from `TopComplexity` object?
I need to change that **for loop** into **stream** "kind" piece of code.

```java
@Data
public class TopComplexity {
   List<SuperComplexProperty> superComplexProperties;
}
@Data
public class SuperComplexProperty {
   List<SimpleProperty> simpleProperties;
   ComplexProperty complexProperty;
}

@Data
public class ComplexProperty {
   List<SimpleProperty> simpleProperties;
}

public class MainClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       TopComplexity top = null;
       List<SimpleProperty> result = new ArrayList<>();
      
       for(SuperComplexProperty prop : top.getSuperComplexProperties) {
          result.addAll(prop.getSimpleProperties());
      
          if(Objects.nonNull(prop.getComplexProperty()) {
              result.addAll(prop.getComplexProperty().getSimpleProperties());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Really appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Stream will not help much here in order to reduce the body of the for loop or its readability. My advice will be change the object design little like adding "public List<SimpleProperty> flatten()" in each object which only takes care for flattenning/summarizing its own complex elements into a simple list (and will invoke nested element's flatten() in turn). Then you only need to call "top.flatten()" and it will return all simple properties that you want.

Comment: Honestly, it is really simple and good idea. Great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix up `flatMap` with a concatenation and ternary operator involving `Stream`s such as:

```
List<SimpleProperty> result = top.getSuperComplexProperties().stream()
        .flatMap(scp -> Stream.concat(
                scp.getSimpleProperties().stream(),
                scp.getComplexProperty() == null ?
                        Stream.empty() :
                        scp.getComplexProperty().getSimpleProperties().stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```